# Correcting for family-wise error rate with series of repeated measures ANOVA?

Tags: repeated-measures, type-i-and-ii-errors

I am trying to make requested revisions to an accepted manuscript, and I am baffled by the following comment from a reviewer:

"Eight hypothesis tests are
   reported in the final paragraph of the results section but the authors do not
   say if they corrected for their Type I familywise error rate. What correction
   was done or should be done?"

To give background, I had a pre- and post-test design, and change was assessed on eight different (theoretically distinct) variables. So, basically, I conducted eight separate repeated measures ANOVAs. I can understand that Type I error rate would be inflated from doing multiple tests, but I have not come across any correction for use with a series of RM ANOVA. Is there a standard procedure or recommended correction?

Comment: Because they are "(theoretically distinct) variables", you could simply state that the eight tests represent different families of tests and therefore each test is conducted with an alpha of .05. Otherwise, if you were in fact to adjust your alpha level, you could use a Bonferroni correction and use an alpha of .05/8.